# batch add logo to all images in folder with imagemagick with terminal command

Tags: terminal, imagemagick, batch-processing

So i searched over the internet but i can't find a simple command to batch add logo to images.

All that i find are either some scripts or website php commands and none for batch use.

I have a folder where i have about 50 images. And i have simple logo.png image outside folder.

And i just need to batch apply logo.png image to all the 50 images in my folder over the terminal command.

I have tried various solutions over the net that i found but none of them seems to be working (none of them is actually just a terminal command they are either scripts or for websites)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the "mogrify" command:

```
mogrify -gravity south -draw "image over 0,10 0,0 /path/to/logo.png" [files]
```

This will overwrite your original files, so if you need to preserve them, copy them into another working directory and run "mogrify" there.  Change the "-gravity" and the position "0,10" to your liking.

Comment: And how do i use it to apply it to all 50 images that i have in folder. i tried with *.jpg * but it's not working.

Comment: Ok at the end worked with full path to folder of images and used *.*